# Would I need an FFMPEG licence?

Tags: licensing

Would I need an FFMPEG licence for an application that I am building? It plays back mp4 videos but I can’t get my head around the lingo in the licences. I don’t need to edit video or convert anything just simply playback mp4 videos. I am aware that I can use it without a licence if my software is open source, it is not though.

Comment: In general, you always need a license. If your project is not open source, you will need to build FFmpeg in LGPL-mode (i.e. by not including GPL code that is not LGPL).  There are instructions for enabling and complying with LGPL of FFmpeg on https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html